# EXE header information (.reloc & .rsrc meaning )

Tags: exe

If you do dumpbin /header  it will give you all 7 section data dumps. 
 .data
 .idata
 .rdata
 .reloc
 .rsrc
 .text
 .textbss

Among this .rsrc and .idata are both content initialized data. These sections are read-only. Then what is the difference between these two?
What is the purpose of the .reloc section?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .rdata section represents read-only data, such as literal strings, constants, and debug directory information.

The .rsrc section contains resource information for a module. It begins with a resource directory structure like most other sections, but this section's data is further structured into a resource tree. The IMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY, shown below, forms the root and nodes of the tree.

source for EXE Format description : 
http://www.csn.ul.ie/~caolan/pub/winresdump/winresdump/doc/pefile2.html

you can find more information here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx